# Restrict Dashboard visibility

Tags: apache-superset

In an instance of Apache Superset, I have an administrator and two users, UA and UB. Each user belongs to a distinct group, GA and GB. The same dataset can be used by users in both GA and GB. I want when UA creates a dashboard, it remains private only to him. If UA presses the "publish" button, his dashboard immediately becomes visible to everyone in the instance. How can I disable the publish button for a group or make his dashboards inaccessible to other groups?

I have tried to change group policies with no success